# Is it possible to connect a Laptop to an Network via Internet?

Tags: networking, system-administration

Sorry for rather dumb question, but I seriously have no idea about this topic.

There is a company network that allows each laptop to access the company server. I can access the network, when I am connected to the wifi of the router of the company.

Now the next step would be, to connect my Laptop from my home wifi (internet) to the network of the company.

My questions are:

1. Is this possible at all?
2. If yes, what would be the correct **terms** to search for resources on this topic
3. Are there any security considerations?

From my understanding there might be the possibility to access the network, by accessing directly the ip of the router? And then have the router somehow authenticate my machine?

It's weird but I would love to be able from my home.

Answer (score 1):

```
-Yes
-Lots of ways(VPN,Hamachi,RDP)
-each of them has their own flaws but mostly secure as long as you keep your ip to yourself
```

more of this:
    https://resolve.co.uk/blog/article/how-to-connect-to-your-work-network-from-outside-the-office